# Fetching from app/api/sendmail/route.ts produces a 405 method not allowed. Nextjs 14.1.0

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, nodemailer, next.js14

Using Nextjs 14.1.0 typescript and facing issue with POST request when attempting to submit a form in my application using fetch to a serverless (Nodemailer) function (sendemail.ts). Verified correct URL (no more 404 error) and server-side code for handling POST requests. Network inspection shows 405 method not allowed. Seeking assistance in identifying and resolving the this error. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

contact.tsx

```
 const [submissionError, setSubmissionError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (
    values: typeof initialValues,
    { setSubmitting }: { setSubmitting: (isSubmitting: boolean) => void }
  ) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/sendmail", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to submit form");
      }

      console.log("Form submitted successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting form:", error);
      setSubmissionError("Failed to submit form. Please try again later.");
    } finally {
      setSubmitting(false);
    }
  };
```

route.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

export async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { name, mobileNumber, email, option, requirements } = req.body;

    try {
      
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 587,
        secure: false, 
        auth: {
          user: "dummy@gmail.com",
          pass: "*****",
        },
      });

      // Send email
      await transporter.sendMail({
        from: "dummy@gmail.com", 
        to: "dummy@gmail.com", 
        subject: "New Contact Form Submission", 
        text: `
          Name: ${name}
          Mobile Number: ${mobileNumber}
          Email: ${email}
          Option: ${option}
          Requirements: ${requirements}
        `, 
      });

      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occurred while sending email:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "Failed to send email" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ success: false, error: "Method Not Allowed" });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually mixing the pattern of `app router` (new router) and `pages router` (old router).

In the pages router, we could create a file in `pages/api` folder such as `pages/api/send-mail.js` and we could write the same code that you've provided here (2nd code block) and then we could send our request to it `fetch("/api/send-mail")`

but in the `app router` which was introduced in NextJS version 13.4. We can create a file as you've already done: `app/api/send-mail/route.js` (we could name the `api` folder anything but `api` is more convenient). Then we export functions with the same name of the methods in UPPERCASE:

```js
export const POST = (req: Request) => {
    const { name, mobileNumber, email, option, requirements } = await req.json()

    try {
        ...

        return Response.json({ success: true })
    } catch (e) {
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success: false }), {
            status: 500
        })
    }
}
```

You can read more about route handlers in the official documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)

Comment: Appreciated, thanks a lot